# How to parse JSON object in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to invoke "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all" from a Angular application and when displaying the results in the HTML page, i am able to parse Name, flag , capital but when tried to display Currency its showing as [object object]

Here is the code I have written in html

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let c of data">
      <td>{{ c.name.common }}</td>
      <td>{{ c.capital }}</td>
      <td>{{ c.flag }}</td>
       <td>{{ c.currencies }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here is the code i have written in Service

```
 public getContrires():any {
    return this._httpClient.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all');
  }
```

Result in HTML output coming as below

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I tried below in the html but still no luck

```
<td *ngFor="let cur of c.currencies">{{ curr.name }}</td>
```

Comment: try `c.currencies[0]`. you'll get an idea hopefully.

Comment: @MahdiZarei unfortunatelly currencies is not an array, it is an object, more like a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.currencies` is INDEED a nested object. In order to get the symbol of the currencies, you need to drill to that object. Like so:

```html
<td>{{ c.currencies[Object.keys(c.currencies)[0]].symbol }}</td>
```

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate object properties using [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

> Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

It is the best approach since a country can adopt more then a single currency

[image]

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of products">
    {{ c?.name?.official }} <br />
    <div *ngFor="let d of c?.currencies | keyvalue">
      {{ d.value['name'] }} - {{ d.value['symbol'] }}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqmwmm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproducts.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.ts)